# Error migrating data with models from django-address app

Tags: django, django-models

I'm doing a data migration, and using django-address for geographical addresses.
I am able to save an address, and everything else seems to work except when I try to assign an address to a building I get the error "Invalid address value."

Migration file:

```
from django.db import migrations
​
def forward_data_migration(apps, schema_editor):
    Address = apps.get_model("address", "Address")
    Locality = apps.get_model("address", "Locality")
    Property = apps.get_model("myApp", "Property")
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    
    Locality.objects.using(db_alias).bulk_create([
        Locality(name="Foo",)
    ])
    
    Address.objects.using(db_alias).bulk_create([
        Address(raw="1 Fake street", locality=Locality.objects.get(name="Foo"), ),
    ])
    
    Property.objects.using(db_alias).bulk_create([
        Property(building_name="Test building", address=Address.objects.get(raw="1 Fake street") ),
    ])
```

Property model:

```
class Property(UUIDTimeStampedModel):
    building_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = AddressField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Address models: https://github.com/furious-luke/django-address/blob/master/address/models.py

The Address app seems to have a function that checks whether the value being passed to it is a valid instance of "Address" but I don't know why this check fails.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's a bit of a bug in the library. The historical model you get from `apps.get_model("address", "Address")` is not compatible with `isinstance(..., Address)` (where `Address` is the current model).

While in general using historical models is strongly recommended, in this instance, you might be fine using the current model (a local `from ... import Address` import) instead of the historical model when creating those objects.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. Unfortunately when I change the import to "from address.models import Address" I get a new error... ValueError: Cannot assign "<Address: 1 Fake street>": "Property.address" must be a "Address" instance.